# Programmatically changing path and filename in WebBrowser's "Save as" dialog

Tags: vb.net

I have this `Private Sub` which **automatically download files** from a web page using `WebBrowser` control. There is any way to change (programmatically) path and filename before user click on save button of `WebBrowser` "Save As" dialog?

```
Private Sub File_Download()
    Dim _Elements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each _Element As HtmlElement In _Elements
        If _Element.GetAttribute("value").Contains("Download") Then
            _Element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd say unless using some kind of UI automation, the answer is probably no.

Comment: @VisualVincent: There is any way to bypass `WebBrowser`'s `SaveFileDialog` and "make" my own or something? Or any other way than `WebBrowser` to do same thing? To find a button into a web page, click it and download the file... Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: There's no way that I know of. The only thing I can think of is finding another web browser control that lets you control downloads. Try looking into GeckoFX and one of its forks created by someone called "hindlemail": https://stackoverflow.com/q/16019107

Comment: I found this GeckoFX web browser control and I am working on it, thank you very much!!!

Comment: @VisualVincent: I can't use it in vb.net... I have make relevant question here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407395/using-geckowebbrowser-v45-0-34-0-in-a-vb-net-project ). Take a look if you have some free time!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used Gecko, so I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Oh OK, no problem!!!