# Using GeckoWebBrowser (v45.0.34.0) in a VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, gecko, geckofx

I am trying to make `GeckoWebBrowser` (version 45.0.34.0) control to work into my **VB.NET** project with no luck!!!

Here is the steps I follow...

**1.** I do right click on my **project** into **Solution Explorer** list and then **Manage NuGet Packages**.

**2.** I find and **install** Geckofx45.

**3.** Then I go into my **Project's properties**, into **Compile tab** and I change **Target CPU** to **x86**.

**4.** I **Rebuild** my project.

**5.** Then I add `GeckoWebBrowser` control into my **Toolbox** by selecting the **Geckofx-Winforms.dll** file from `...\packages\Geckofx45.45.0.34\lib\net45` folder.

**6.** I add a `GeckoWebBrowser` control into my **form** and just for test, I do `GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")` into my form's `Load` event.

**7.** I **Start** my app and I get nothing!!!

There is any step I miss or something?

Comment: For some reason the community wants to close this question as "too broad". I honestly don't see what would be too broad about it. He explained **the exact steps** he took and (perhaps a little fuzzy, but still) that the outcome is that nothing's happening. How is that "too broad"?

Comment: I took a peek at the [GeckoFX wiki](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/wiki/Home) and saw that they were calling `Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox")` prior to initializing the web browser. What happens if you put this before navigating in the `Form.Load` event? If it still doesn't work, also try removing the web browser from the form and create it through code after the Xpcom call.

Comment: I found the solution my friend Vincent!!! Now I am writing the solution in steps, for those who want to use GeckoWebBrowser in VB.NET.  :)

Comment: @VisualVincent: Please don't close this question my friend, I am coming with an answer!!!

Comment: I am not the one wanting to close it, but others are...

Comment: Oh sorry my friend I thought they told you to close it!!! Anyway, I gave the right solution so I hope they don't close it after all. :)

Comment: Nah, this is a democracy. No one can force me to close it. What I was referring to is that I can _see_ that others have voted for this to be closed, which I don't understand because to me this is a perfectly valid question (it's certainly not too broad anyway).

Comment: Yes, I just saw it, I have get four negative votes... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After an exhausting(!!!) research over the internet, I managed to make it work!!! Here is the steps for anyone who want to use GeckoWebBrowser to his/her VB.NET project.

**1.** Create a new VB.NET project or just open an existing one.

**2.** Go to menu **Project** and click on **Manage NuGet Packages**.

**3.** Click on **Browse** tab and search for **Geckofx45**.

**4.** Choose the one with description: **library that allows embeding gecko in C# applications** and click **Install** button.

**5.** Close **NuGet** window and go to your project's **Properties**.

**6.** Into **Application** tab click the **View Application Events** button.

**7.** Delete everything in there and paste this part of code and save it.

```
Imports Gecko
Imports System.IO
Namespace My
    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    '
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active.
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Protected Overrides Function OnStartup(ByVal eventArgs As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) As Boolean
            Dim ProfileDirectory As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Firefox\Profile"
            If Not Directory.Exists(ProfileDirectory) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(ProfileDirectory)
            End If
            Xpcom.ProfileDirectory = ProfileDirectory
            Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox")
            Return True
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**8.** Now, go back to your project **Properties**, click on **Compile** tab and set the **Target CPU** value to **x86**.

**9.** Build or Rebuild your project.

**10a.** To add `GeckoWebBrowser` control into your **Toolbox**, first create a new **Tab** by then name **GeckoFX 45** or whatever you like.

**10b.** Right click on it and click on **Choose Items**.

**10b.** Go into **.NET Framework Componetns** and click **Browse** button.

**10c.** Find **Geckofx-Winforms.dll** into `your-project-folder\packages\Geckofx45.45.0.34\lib\net45\` and click **Open** button.

**10d.** Make sure that `GeckoWebBrowser` is checked and then click **OK**.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! :)

Comment: Now I am trying to see if I can make it work for x64 too and I'll update my answer!!!

Comment: Hi. i have problem with adding in to the Toolbar. Always giving me an error ,,There are no components...". Maybe can you suggest a solution? Thanks

Comment: @RobertNegreanu: That means you stuck on step **10a** ?

Comment: Stuck on 10c :) Maybe I will try with an older version

Comment: @RobertNegreanu: Yes, **10c** sorry. Which version are you trying now?

Comment: At the moment I'm trying 45.0. Maybe is some issue with this version

Comment: @RobertNegreanu: Try to download the latest version using NuGet and inform me if worked...

Comment: I did like that. I'm using windows 64bit, but I've tried to use 32bit and 64bit with same result

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm trying to use in C#

Comment: @RobertNegreanu: Oh no my friend, this steps are only for vb.net!!! For C# please take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8f8Iv1f040) and [here](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/using-the-gecko-web-browser-in-a-c-winforms-project/)!!!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I saw already both tutorials but I've got same error. But thanks

Comment: @RobertNegreanu: You are welcome my friend, my pleasure!!! :) You can also take a look [here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/wiki/Home) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues?status=new&status=open), if you hanven't already did.